# Any way to load about:tabs in an IFRAME?

Tags: html, iframe

Is `about:Tabs` a valid src URI for an `IFRAME`? Alternatively, how else would i load `about:Tabs` as part of another page?

```
<html>
<body>
<p>some other content</p>
<iframe src="about:Tabs" width="100%" height="80%">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't seem to work, at least in IE9 and FF7.

Answer (score 0):

the `about:` is for browser specific, internal document/settings page(s). For example, FF's `about:config`. why would you want to link to that anyway?

best thing to do if you just want the content is to copy and paste the code into your own html file

Comment: I want to add some hard links and other dynamic info above the `about:tabs` content. Cut-paste doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: what's your goal? I'd love to edit my answer and try to help you out more, but I need more info about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I use `about:tabs` for new tabs, but would like to add some more functionality, like some static links and dynamic content above(jquery). So it'd be more than just my "popular sites" but a dashboard of sorts.

Comment: but why would you load that into a frame? the about:tabs in IE, I believe, was simply to inform users about how tabs work. You wouldn't have programmatic control of over the content anyway

Comment: No no. `about:tabs` is a speed-dial like page (a la Opera) with most frequently visited links in a grid. I find it useful, but would like to "enhance" it by including it in an IFRAME. It's pretty clear that i'm going to have to do something else, but i thought i'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

`about:Tabs` doesn't work in Firefox. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme) `about:tabs` is Internet Explorer specific.

From testing it seems you can use `about:blank` and `about:robots` in an `iframe` in Firefox, but it doesn't work for things like `about:config` or `about:plugins`. I would assume this is for security reasons.

`about:tabs` works if I type this URL into my address bar in Internet Explorer 9, but not in an `iframe`. Again probably for security reasons.

Comment: Oh, right, forgot it wasn't valid in FF. Not sure about the security concern, as IFRAME content isn't accessible by the including page. Thanks for testing the other `about:` URIs, though.

Comment: Yeah on it's own it shouldn't be a concern, but there is certain tricks you can do by overlaying a div on top of the iframe to hide it (the same kind of tricks which post to your facebook without your permission). Also if there ever was a vulnerability which allowed access to the iframe then it could be an issue.